# BMW x3 triad of lights + AirBag and LowTire light

Tags: bmw, abs, supplemental-restraint-system, transfer-case

2008 BMW X3 started to have low tire pressure light on all the time despite all tires looking visually ok. And, besides that, occasionally, when I step on accelerator there is a beep and ABS, BRAKE, AirBag and 4x4 lights turn on. Also, when I turn off the car there is this occasional "click, click, click ..." noise coming from front.

[image]

So far a googling has lead me to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bh6HvYcn-HA) where condition with subset of symptoms that I have is called "bmw triad of lights" due to transfer case failure (nylon gear chewed up). Presumably it causes the "click, click, click" noise that occasionaly happens on my car too.

Battery was replaced 2 months ago because the old one failed.

**Since I have superset of symptoms ("low tire" and "airbag" light on), my question to BMW folks - is the clicking noise definite proof that transfer case gear needs to be replaced as described in that video? I just don't want to spend 3 hours removing parts to realize that issue could have been somewhere else.**

Comment: On my E91, I've had similar symptoms (dashboard lighting up like an xmas-tree) caused by wheel speed sensor failure. Probably a good idea to plug it in and read out the codes before making any assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the transfer case actuator gear (that in my case had one side chewed up the same way as in video) and the "triad of lights" and "low tire" lights turned off.